# Wordpress: display static image over slide show

Tags: wordpress, plugins, slider, themes

I have a client that is looking for a Wordpress plugin or theme that will display an image over a rotating slider, similar to the home page here: https://www.threebakers.com/

Any thoughts on an out-of-the box solution, or do I need to build this one by hand?

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, I did this exact thing on this site here:

http://www.gilbertmeatlocker.com

Its using the popular Flex Slider, but its not Wordpress.  I was working with Drupal on that particular site, so its a custom implement of the stand-alone javascript Flex Slider.

I had to fiddle around with z-index and I used negative-margins to move elements into position.

That particular implementation on gilbertmeatlocker.com is extra complex because the silver frame around the edge is also overlapping the Flex Slider.   I would recommend *not* doing a frame like this if possible, though.  It added some serious bugs that were difficult to make work on all browsers.

Putting a single image over the slider like your bakery example or the gilbertmeatlocker.com logo shouldn't be a problem though.

If noone else recommends something better, you could try Flex Slider.  There is a Wordpress version of it.